# Configuring a sticky MAC address on IOS

Tags: cisco-ios, port-security, command

What is the use case of the `Switch(config-if)# switchport port-security mac-address sticky 0000.1111.1111` command?

By definition, a *sticky* address is a learned *secure* address that is added to the running configuration. By definition, a *configured* address is a *secure* address that is statically configured via `Switch(config-if)# switchport port-security mac-address 0000.2222.2222`.

By manually adding a sticky address, I've added a configured address. The command seems to me redundant and contradictory to the concept of a sticky MAC address.

---

Even the `debug port-security` entries in the system log call a sticky a configured address. After having issued `Switch# clear port-security sticky address 0000.1111.1111`, there are entries such as `PSECURE: Deleting secure MAC address 0000.1111.1111 on port` and `PSECURE: Address is sticky on port` and `PSECURE: Delete configured address: 0000.1111.1111 from subblock`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While you *can* manually configure a sticky address, it is not usually used that way (and in fact Cisco recommends against it):

> You can configure MAC addresses to be sticky. These can be dynamically
>   learned or manually configured, stored in the address table, and added
>   to the running configuration. If these addresses are saved in the
>   configuration file, the interface does not need to dynamically relearn
>   them when the switch restarts. **Although sticky secure addresses can be
>   manually configured, it is not recommended**.
>
> You can configure an interface to convert the dynamic MAC addresses to
>   sticky secure MAC addresses and to add them to the running
>   configuration by enabling sticky learning. To enable sticky learning,
>   enter the switchport port-security mac-address sticky command. When
>   you enter this command, the interface converts all the dynamic secure
>   MAC addresses, including those that were dynamically learned before
>   sticky learning was enabled, to sticky secure MAC addresses.
>
> (source: [Catalyst 4500 Series Switch Cisco IOS Software Configuration Guide, 12.2(20)EWA](http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/switches/lan/catalyst4500/12-2/20ewa/configuration/guide/conf/port_sec.html) - emphasis is mine)

In other words, when you want to manually configure a MAC address on a port, you use

```
switchport port-security mac-address nnnn.nnnn.nnnn
```

but when you want the switch to automatically learn the first MAC seen on a port and remember that (even if there is no traffic seen from that MAC for a long time), then you use:

```
switchport port-security mac-address sticky
```

and after the swich learns a MAC address, you will see that it has automatically added:

```
switchport port-security mac-address sticky nnnn.nnnn.nnnn
```